# How to filter by particular date

Tags: excel, vba

In the below code, i have to filter by date but it is not filtering by the date which i have mentioned in inputbox. I feel there is something wrong in filter format.

Please help. Many Thanks

```
sDate = InputBox("Choose Start date (dd/mm/yyyy)")
EDate = InputBox("Choose End date (dd/mm/yyyy)")
 Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BP$4181").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria2:=sDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This :

```
Sub testDate()
Dim sDate As Date, _
    eDate As Date

sDate = CDate(InputBox("Choose Start date (dd/mm/yyyy)"))
eDate = CDate(InputBox("Choose End date (dd/mm/yyyy)"))

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BP$4181").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & sDate, Criteria2:="<=" & eDate

End Sub
```

As an InputBox gives you a String, you might want to convert it to date before filtering with it

Comment: Could you please let me know how to change it to date.

Comment: Look at the code ;) I added the `CDate()` function which convert a string to a date variable

Comment: I have used this before but still it is not filtering

Comment: Sub Macro1()
Dim sDate As String
Dim EDate As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim n As Integer


sDate = InputBox("Choose Start date (dd/mm/yyyy)")
EDate = InputBox("Choose End date (dd/mm/yyyy)")
 Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$BP$4181").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria2:=CDate(sDate)

Comment: Thanks for the help!! but i have to filter sdate value in one column(i.e field 8) and Edate in other column(i.e field 9).

Comment: You are welcome, hope it was enough to lead you on the right way ;)